# What is the correct format of the test input for LSTM neural network?

Tags: deep-learning, lstm, forecasting

I have learned some tutorials for **LSTM** time series prediction. According to that tutorials, My training data format would be like,

**NOTE :**
This data is only for example. this is not the real data.

```
x  y
x1 x2
x2 x3
x3 x4
.  .
.  .
x9 x10
```

I  am using the basic **LSTM Model**,

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(len(input), input_shape=(1, look_back)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
```

So after `model.fit()`. I am confused a bit how to test predict the next value of the series. I don't know How to find the next time series Data `x11` ?

I also tried with shown below inputs to find the `x11`,

**Methods:**

1. [x10]
   **Or**
2. [ x2,x3,x4,...x10]

As far as i learnt method 1 is right. But **Method 2** provides better accuracy than **Method 1**. So I don't know which way is correct to predict the next time series data ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Sean Owen, I have edited my question. and i hope it is understandable

Comment: This should probably be closed on SO as cross posting is discouraged